# Mysql and PHP to display all user data in a html list

Tags: php, html, mysql, rss, feed

I have an issue, I'm creating a RSS feed script, although it's only displaying the data all in one row, for example: **MorganJonesMaleYasserkhattak**
Rather than

**Morgan Jones Male**

**Yasser Khattak**

I'm unsure of how to display the data in a Html file so I can display it with CSS style.

Here is my current script:

```
<?php

// PDO connect *********
function connect() {
    return new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=pdo_ret', 'root', 'Af2vaz93j68', array(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION, PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => "SET NAMES utf8"));
}

$pdo = connect();

// posts *******************************
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM users ORDER BY id DESC';
$query = $pdo->prepare($sql);
$query->execute();
$rs_post = $query->fetchAll();

// The XML structure
$data = '<html lang="en">';
$data .= '<rss version="2.0">';
$data .= '<channel>';
foreach ($rs_post as $row) {
    $data .= '<item>';
    $data .= '<firstname>'.$row['firstname'].'</firstname>';
    $data .= '<lastname>'.$row['lastname'].'</lastname>';
    $data .= '<gender>'.$row['gender'].'</gender>';
    $data .= '</item>';
}
$data .= '</channel>';
$data .= '</rss> ';

?>

<html>
<h1><b><echo><?= $data ?></echo></b></h1>
</html>
```

Comment: Have a look at `XSLT` if you want to style XML.

Comment: you're stuffing xml into an html document. pretty much all of those xml tags will be unknown/invalid html tags, and therefore skipped by the browser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ahm, *echo* tags doesn't exists. To display it as pre-formatted HTML, you can use the `<pre>` tag:

```
<h1><b><pre><?php echo $data ?></pre></b></h1>
```

Comment: Ah, I see. Although is there anyway I can display the data in a list. For example, 
Morgan Jones Male

Yasser Khattak
As they are two different users. I'm still trying to get my head around this.